# space in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I want to obtain the below output from below code:

```
arg max probability i
i ∈ child(v)
```

I have the below code:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{hhline}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}



\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
         arg \! max \! probability \! i   \\
           i \in \! child(V)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

but the result does not make space in the first line

```
argmaxprobabilityi
i∈child(V)
```

**How can i fix the missed spaces?**

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE. Get rid of `\!`, it deletes the space.

Comment: `\!` is a negative space in math mode, various commands exist to insert normal spaces, see [https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Spacing_in_math_mode](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Spacing_in_math_mode).

Answer (score 24):

`\!` creates a small negative space (i.e. moves things closer together). You could use `\,` for a small space, or just `\` (or `~`) for a bigger space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator\prb{probability}
\DeclareMathOperator\child{child}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
         \arg \ \max \ \prb \ i   \\
           i \in \ \child(V)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the use of `\DeclareMathOperator` from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to get the correct spacing and fonts for 'probability' and 'child'. You don't need this for 'arg' or 'max' because those commands are already defined.

Comment: Note that the backslash requires a space after it, it should really be thought of as 'backslash space". I.e., `\_` but the underscore is space.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg max}

\begin{document}


    \[
    \argmax\limits_{i \in  \mathrm{child}(V)}  \text{probability } i 
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need is this, I guess:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmaxprob}{arg\,max\,probability}
\DeclareMathOperator{\child}{child}

\begin{document}

    \[ \argmaxprob_{i\in \child(V)} i\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]